# Post-Build $(RemoteMachine) Fails to Resolve VS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, post-build-event

SO I must be doing something wrong because this seems so straight forward yet it isn't working. I referenced all the build macros [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx)

As I understand it I went to the project properties then the debug tab. There I found under working directory "Use Remote Machine" I checked it and entered my remote machine name. \FarOut

I then went up to Build Events and added this line:

```
copy /Y "$(TargetDir)*.pdb" "$(RemoteMachine)assembly\"
```

On FarOut there is a shared folder for the pdb's called Assembly.

When I build however $(RemoteMachine) does not resolve to anything...so I get a build error.

```
copy /Y "C:\Users\...\bin\Debug\*.pdb" "assembly\"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Not reading the MSDN article you linked closely enough.  The $(RemoteMachine) property only exists in C++ projects.  The C# IDE has no knowledge of it and doesn't use it.  You won't get an error either, you might as well type $(foobar) and get the same result.  Undefined properties evaluate to nothing.

There's not much parity between the C++ and C# IDEs when it comes to configuration properties.  C++ has many, many more of them.  And a dedicated View + Property Manager window to keep track of them.  And the notion of property sheets to save their values as a set that can be reused in other projects.  C++ builds are a lot more convoluted.

It's not like you can't make it work, just add the property to the .csproj file with a text editor.  But there's no convenience to doing it that way, you might as well edit the postbuild event.  Consider a network drive letter mapping as a more convenient way, so you can hardcode Z:\ in the project settings.  Do note the "To deploy additional files" section at the bottom of [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x6by8d2.aspx), it isn't clear to me if that's what you really want to do.  The .pdb files should not be a problem.

Comment: I made two mistakes actually. 1. Not reading the MSDN article closely enough and 2. Ass-U-me-ing. I did read about it being for C++ projects but I ASSUMED that VS Team at Msoft would NOT display that property setting for a c# project if it weren't available.